# How to slice a id and grab a number?

Tags: jquery, class, trim, slice

I have a jQuery id like

```
<div id="myid-page-top-0">
    some stuff
</div>
```

I want to use jQuery to grab the `"0"` from the end of the `#id`. I have tried like

`$('div').slice(-1,0);`

But this doesn't work ? Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of slice, which would only work if your id contains numbers 0-9, not if it is say 10 or 11, you should base it off of the dashes.

Something like:

```
var id = "myid-page-top-0";
alert(id.split("-")[3]);
```

or in your code something like:

```
var number = $('div').attr('id').split("-")[3];
```

Comment: thanks for the response :) which is better in terms of performance do you know ? i.e. `$('div').attr('id').replace('myid-page-top-', '');` or your `$('div').attr('id').split("-")[3];` ?

Comment: the difference is so minuscule that it would be inconsequential.  It really just comes down to preference at that point.

Comment: Performance-wise, I'd say _id.substr(id.lastIndexOf('-')+1)_ is better than either.

Answer (score 2):

`$('div')` is an object, you want the ID:

```
$('div').attr('id').slice(-1,0);
```

If your numbers go into double digits though you might run into problems, it might be better to do it like this:

```
$('div').attr('id').replace('myid-page-top-', '');
```

Comment: ah cool :) the 2nd works but the `.slice` doesn't - i.e. see http://jsfiddle.net/BM5Vz/ - i'll give the second a whirl :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go buddy. Tested and working. iterates through all divs and returns the ending number

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {

                            $('div').each(function(i) {
                                                   var id = $(this).attr("id");

                                var slices = id.substr(id.length - 1, 1); 
                                alert(slices);
                                });
                            }
                            );
  </script>


<div id="myid-page-top-0">
    some stuff
</div>

<div id="myid-page-top-1">
    some stuff
</div>

<div id="myid-page-top-2">
    some stuff
</div>
```