# alternative for this.id.slice(-1), my code will soon stop working

Tags: jquery

I just found that *this.id.slice(-1)* only work from id 0 to 9.

I need a new alternative before it stop working. This is what i have.

```
$("a.toggle_showhide_links").click(function() {
  $("#showhide" +this.id.slice(-1)).slideToggle(400);
});
```

this is a loop that runs at least 5 times.

```
<tr>
    <td><a id='link-".$x."' class='toggle_showhide' href='#!'>CLICK</a></td>
</tr>
<tr id='showhide-".$x."' style='display:none;'>
    <td style='border:1px solid black;' colspan='2'>
           <!-- Hideable contents-->
    </td>
</tr>";
```

and Finally, i tried this from this [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7771197/how-to-slice-a-id-and-grab-a-number)

```
var number = $('tr').attr('id').split("-")[1];

$( "a.toggle_showhide_links_").click(function() {
     $("#showhide-" + (number.split("-")[1])).slideToggle(400);
    });
```

[image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined]

Comment: How about `$('#' + this.id.replace('link', 'showhide'))`?

Comment: @FelixKling thank you it works. I'm sure i was going to spend the whole night working on it with no success but you gave me a solution really quick . can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IDs always follow the pattern `link-<number>` and `showhide-<number>`, then a very simple way to produce one ID from the other is to replace the `link` or `showhide` part:

```
$('#' + this.id.replace('link', 'showhide'))
```